# Why has Photos replaced Reader on iGoogle navigation menu?

Tags: gmail, google-reader, picasa-web-albums, igoogle

In my iGoogle list (when logged into Gmail), I currently have:

```
Gmail   Calendar   Documents  Photos   Web   More v
```

Until today, I had:

```
Gmail   Calendar   Documents  Reader   Web   More v
```

My question is, why did it change from `Reader` to `Photos` and how do I change it back?

Comment: They should simply add it somewhere in the settings on what we want in that list.. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like somebody did something and it might get fixed.

From a [Google Employee](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=2a91a65086157dbf&hl=en&fid=2a91a65086157dbf00049a61ef8a91d2&hltp=2) on their official forums:

> Hi folks,
>
> Sorry if I caused confusion with my first post - I meant to say that we're trying to get the Google Reader *link* fixed in Gmail. Google Reader itself isn't broken.
>
> Until we do, you can find the link to Google Reader by clicking on 'More'  at the top of your Gmail window- Reader is the first in the drop down menu.
>
> Cheers,
>
> Shirley